# How to stack one big, then two small on top, then one big again

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: This is how i want to stack the divs].

Have a look at the above image. That's how I want to stack some `div`s. How can I do that with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9frL9e55/1/).

I've followed the following div structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">Some text</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="col-xs-12">some text</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">some text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```